# How do I solve pod install error in terminal?

Tags: firebase, terminal, cocoapods, xcode11

I’ve added a new pod to my already existing podfile which worked perfectly and I wrote pod install in Terminal  . It starts installing but when generating pods project is says ‘oh ,no an error occurred’ and now my project fails to build .

Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.3)
Using Firebase (6.6.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (6.1.0)
Using FirebaseAuth (6.2.2)
Using FirebaseAuthInterop (1.0.0)
Using FirebaseCore (6.2.0)
Using FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (1.0.0)
Using FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (1.0.0)
Using FirebaseDatabase (6.0.0)
Using FirebaseFirestore (1.4.3)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (4.2.3)
Using GTMSessionFetcher (1.2.2)
Using GoogleAppMeasurement (6.1.0)
Using GoogleDataTransport (1.0.0)
Using GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (1.0.0)
Using GoogleUtilities (6.2.4)
Using Protobuf (3.9.0)
Using gRPC-C++ (0.0.9)
Using gRPC-Core (1.21.0)
Using leveldb-library (1.20)
Using nanopb (0.3.901)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

#### Command

```
/usr/local/bin/pod install
```

#### Report

- What did you do?
- What did you expect to happen?
- What happened instead?

#### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.7.5
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3
        Host : Mac OS X 10.15 (19A526h)
       Xcode : 11.0 (11M382q)
         Git : git version 2.21.0 (Apple Git-122)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 86c8d2a54cdff44b97176caed26d7d52378c1143
```

#### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.1.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.3.1
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0
```

#### Podfile

```rb
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Do It !' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Do It !

  target 'Do It !Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'Do It !UITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Database'


end
```

#### Error

```
RuntimeError - Developer workspace file reference type is not yet supported (Pods/Pods.xcodeproj)
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.11.0/lib/xcodeproj/workspace/file_reference.rb:72:in `absolute_path'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.11.0/lib/xcodeproj/workspace.rb:203:in `block in load_schemes'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.11.0/lib/xcodeproj/workspace.rb:202:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.11.0/lib/xcodeproj/workspace.rb:202:in `load_schemes'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.11.0/lib/xcodeproj/workspace.rb:85:in `from_s'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.11.0/lib/xcodeproj/workspace.rb:66:in `new_from_xcworkspace'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.5/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb:102:in `create_workspace'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.5/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb:71:in `integrate!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.5/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:780:in `block in integrate_user_project'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.5/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.5/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:776:in `integrate_user_project'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.5/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.5/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:51:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.5/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.5/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=Developer+workspace+file+reference+type+is+not+yet+supported+%28Pods%2FPods.xcodeproj%29&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
Found no similar issues. To create a new issue, please visit:
https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues/new

[!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `12.4` on target `Do It !` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.